# Parse html and keep into associate array in awk

Tags: html, linux, shell, unix

A html document can have multiple  tags like below:

```
<h2>
   <a id="id1" name="name1"></a>
   test1
</h2>
<h2>
   <a id="id2" name="name2"></a>
   test2
</h2>
```

I am iterating over all `<h2>` tag in document to get the inner html of `<h2>`
using `awk` like below:

```
file='/var/www/html/test.html' 

awk -F" *</?h2> *\n?" -v RS="^$" '{
for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)
{
   printf "%s", $i       
   //parse to get the 'id' and 'text'
   arr['id']=value //need to do something here
}
}' $file
```

and i am getting output like:

```
<a id="id1" name="name1"></a>
 test1
<a id="id2" name="name2"></a>
 test2
```

Now, i want to parse the anchor inside awk loop to get the `id` as key and description(for ex: test1) as value.

So, that if i access array as `${arr[@]}` outside the `awk` i should get the below output something like:

```
{'id1':'test1','id2':'test2'}
```

Comment: Sorry not clear is it output should be in exact same form `{'id1':'test1','id2':'test2'}`? Or it should be in a bash array form?

Comment: yes bash array is fine.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Cross posting is generally not recommended. You've just posted this on Unix.SE [How to extract html between tags?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/485828/112235)